# How to merge DataFrames using a key inside of a column of a dict type?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two datasets like this:

```py
In [2]: df_names = pd.DataFrame([
   ...:     ['alpha', {'key': 'a'}],
   ...:     ['beta', {'key': 'b'}],
   ...:     ['gamma', {'key': 'g'}],
   ...: ], columns=['name', 'data'])
   ...: df_names

Out[2]: 
    name          data
0  alpha  {'key': 'a'}
1   beta  {'key': 'b'}
2  gamma  {'key': 'g'}

In [3]: df_symbols = pd.DataFrame([
   ...:     ['α', {'english_letter': 'a'}],
   ...:     ['β', {'english_letter': 'b'}],
   ...:     ['γ', {'english_letter': 'g'}],
   ...: ], columns=['symbol', 'meta'])
   ...: df_symbols

Out[3]: 
  symbol                     meta
0      α  {'english_letter': 'a'}
1      β  {'english_letter': 'b'}
2      γ  {'english_letter': 'g'}
```

Now I'd like to join these two on `['data']['key']` on the left side and `['meta']['english_letter']` on the right side.

Not sure what to add more. How would you do that in an elegant way?

My current approach:

```py
In [4]: df_names['join_key'] = df_names.apply(lambda x: x['data']['key'], axis=1)
   ...: df_symbols['join_key'] = df_symbols.apply(lambda x: x['meta']['english_letter'], axis=1)
   ...: result = pd.merge(df_names, df_symbols, on='join_key')
   ...: result[['name', 'symbol']]

Out[4]: 
    name symbol
0  alpha      α
1   beta      β
2  gamma      γ
```

What I don't like about that is the need of modification of both source datasets.

Comment: Is it really necessary to store those dicts in the dataframe? It looks like all the dicts have the same structure (`{'key': something}` and `{'english_letter': something}`), so why not throw the useless data away and just store `something`)?

Comment: Good point! Of course this is a simplified case. From what I read so far I have a feeling that storing dicts is not generally used in pandas, but the structures I use are way more complicated and "unfolding" or "linearization" would bring too much mess that would complicate further processing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create list by list comprehension, convert to `array`s and use as input to `left_on` and `right_on` parameter in `merge`:

```
a1 = np.array([x['key'] for x in df_names['data']])
a2 = np.array([x['english_letter'] for x in df_symbols['meta']])

r = pd.merge(df_names, df_symbols, left_on=a1, right_on=a2)[['name', 'symbol']]
print (r)
    name symbol
0  alpha      α
1   beta      β
2  gamma      γ
```

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:
Create a new column in each dataframe which will have values of dictionary

```
df_names['val']=df_names['data'].apply(lambda x: x['key'])
df_symbols['val']=df_symbols['meta'].apply(lambda x: x['english_letter'])
```

Merge both dataframes on the newly created column

```
df = df_names.merge(df_symbols, how='inner', on='val')
df.drop(['data','meta','val'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

Output

```
    name    symbol
0   alpha   α
1   beta    β
2   gamma   γ
```